# Cannot update state using react modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a react modal which pops a form and asks for few user settings. I have two tabs where one is for user details and other for endpoint details. Everything works fine but when I'm trying to get the user input and put it in a state, I get errors.

First I tried sending the details on an `onChange` function and I tried changing my state there, but then it trips out the tab anytime I enter something on the input bar; then I tried just getting the user value using (e.target) but then I get an error saying that e is not defined.

I have properly initialized all the functions and binded them to .this as well. Any suggestions on how I can get the user value and update my state? Thanks!
(Cutting bit of the code since its too long and unnecessary.

```
   <Modal
    isOpen={this.state.showSettings}
    onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
    <Tabs className="z-depth-1">
      <Tab title="Endpoint Settings">
        <div id="endpointSetting">
          <br />
          <h5>Please Enter Endpoint Settings</h5>
          <div>
          <form>
            <Row>
              <Col s={6}>
                <p>URI for User Details: </p>
              </Col>
              <Col s={6}>
                <input
                  id="modalInput"
                  name="user_uri"
                  placeholder="eg: localhost:3000/users"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col s={6}>
                <p>URI for Traces Details: </p>
              </Col>
              <Col s={6}>
                <input
                  id="modalInput"
                  placeholder="eg: localhost:3000/traces"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <button className="btn" onClick={this.closeModal}>
      Save and Close Settings
    </button>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: Can you share whole code of the component ?

Comment: I can but its a huge component with about 200 lines. Will that still help ? I can shorten it as much as I can :)

Comment: See on placing onChange's method, you need to use `e.preventDefault()` on method that you are calling. like `onChange = {(e) => this.handleOnChange(e)}` and on method -> `handleOnChange = event => {event.preventDefault();}`

Comment: Did you did this(above implementation) then ?

Comment: Yes I did do e.preventDefault but that's when I got 'e is undefined' error. :/ Then once I tried just getting the input value by giving it a 'name' and using e.target.elements.name.value, it still have me the same error. Let me try implementing it the way you have specified here :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the `input` tag's name and state's property should match,if you are directly calling `setState` on that like  `this.setState({[event.target.name] : event.target.value})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured that the onChange was obviously happening on each key stroke, and it was that which was messing up the tabs for some reason. I simply changed onChange to onBlur and voila, it worked. Dont know why the tabs were messing up.. Maybe because of MaterializeCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example so you can understand Synthetic Events of Reactjs.

```
import React{Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
      constructor(props){
               super(props);
               this.state={value:''};
               this.myFn=this.myFn.bind(this);
               }
      myFn(event){
               this.setState({value:event.target.value});
               }
      render(){
               return(<div className="App">
                      <input onChange=({this.myFn}) type="text"></input>
                      <span>{this.state.value}</span>
                      </div>)
               }
              }
      export default App;
```

Comment: React isnt taking onChange({this.YourFunc}) as a valid syntax so I tried onChange={this.func) but that leads me to the same roblem I had earlier. For some reason it doesnt get the (e) or (event)

Comment: what it say's then?

Comment: I did, Ive tried using this previously when I was starting with React. But in this case it somehow messes up with the Tabs any time I have an on change on the input.. The moment I type, it merges both the tabs but even then it doesnt work. Do you think this could be the tabs or the modal ? Maybe because im using them together ?

Comment: I've updated my example, modal has nothing to do with Reactjs. Try it and tell if it works and you get the idea..If you have uploaded it to github, send me the link of your repository at bilu71115@gmail.com so I can figure it out....

Comment: I know how the onChange works and how its supposed to be set up.. I can work this example already but the problem is when i'm trying to use it with the modal and tabs. I went through this example way before I was starting with React. Any ideas?

Comment: upload your project to github and tell me the name of your repository so I can figure it out easily...